# How to fix "emergency mode" on ubuntu?

Tags: boot, 20.04

I have a dual boot machine, with windows 10 and ubuntu. I tried to fix a partition and to re-add that partition (just a data partition, not the actual boot partition) to ubuntu as fat32.

But now when I reboot the machine into ubuntu I see the following on the screen:

[image]

How to fix that? What is going on?

Comment: Read the error text. Write down the commands it suggest you to run later. Decide if you want to enter the Maintenance mode, or try to Continue booting - depending on the actual error, this might fail. The top line on the screen dump suggests that there might be some interesting errors above, but they might also be in the system logs.

Comment: what error text? It suggests to check the journal, but there are million of entries. It was a misconfiguration in /etc/fstab by the way. But then I am unable to reboot in that emergency mode. `sudo reboot` does not work at all.

Comment: Have you fixed the misconfig ? At the point shown in the screen dump, you either press Enter OR Ctrl-d ... when you get a prompt you can type 'systemctl default, 'systemctl reboot' or 'exit' as described.

Comment: Yes fixed it. It was the /etc/fstab